# How to move file a from internal storage of android?

Tags: java, android, file, kotlin, internal-storage

I want to move a file from the android internal storage app-specific directory.
`e.g:` from `/data/user/0/com.app.package/cache` to `/data/user/0/com.app.package/files`


I know I can copy all content and do stuff like reading bits, copy the content, re-write it to the new location and then delete the original one.
**BUT** 
I don't want to do this, it's not moving but copying stuff.
So, does anyone knows here any simple method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to move with this code

```
File from = new File(oldPathWithFileName);
File to = new File(newPathWithFileName);
from.renameTo(to);
```

this should work only if both files are placed in same storage (thats your case), won't work when you want to move from e.g. internal storage to SD

Comment: yes, I have already got it and was surprisingly it worked.